# SQL statement - how to use multiple CASE with different SELECT?

Tags: mysql, sql, case

I'm pretty new with SQL, and I'm using a PHP Generator software for Rapid application development.

I have a dropdown to which I need to apply a SQL statement for the lookup, to populate the dropdown.

If this was Javascript it would be easy, but not sure how to proceed with SQL.

My table has items with different types, the types of each item can be:

```
'P'
'B'
'O'
'S'
```

when I open an Item, it loads its informations, and I need to populate this dropdown based on the Item type.

The dropdown in my Table is a `Tinyint`.

For the selected Item, I have the `ItemID` (PK in the Table) in a global variable, from there, to retrieve the `Type` of that item, a simple `SELECT` should work:

```
SELECT ItemType
FROM TblItem
WHERE ItemID = [ItemID]
```

so with this `SELECT` now I have my ItemType.

From there, now I need to populate my dropdown based on the ItemType

With Javascript I would do something like:

```
switch(ItemType) {
  case 'B':
    // code block
    break;
  case 'P':
    // code block
    break;
 case 'S':
    // code block
    break;
 case 'O':
    // code block
    break;
}
```

and for each CASE code block, I would put a different SELECT statement to populate my dropdown, for example:

```
case 'B':
  SELECT 0 AS TaskID, 'Installation' AS TaskName
  UNION
  SELECT 1 AS TaskID, 'Setup' AS TaskName
  UNION
  SELECT 2 AS TaskID, 'Feedback' AS TaskName
  UNION
  SELECT 3 AS TaskID, 'Customer' AS TaskName

case 'P':
  SELECT 4 AS TaskID, 'Production' AS TaskName
  UNION
  SELECT 5 AS TaskID, 'Debug' AS TaskName
  UNION
  SELECT 6 AS TaskID, 'Review' AS TaskName
  UNION
  SELECT 7 AS TaskID, 'Network' AS TaskName
```

and so on, so each time I open the details view of an Item, I retrieve the `ItemID` in a global variable, then I should use this `ID` to retrieve the `ItemType` as shown above, and finally, implement some kind of `CASE` statement in SQL to fill the dropdown based on the Type

thank you

Comment: In `SQL` the `CASE` operator is more like an immediate-if.  `CASE WHEN x=y THEN a WHEN x<y THEN b WHEN x>y THEN c ELSE d END`.  It allows you to code scalar valued functions, it's not for programmatic flow control, for that you just use `IF` statements in your procedural code *(outside of any `SELECT` statement)*.  You are better served refactoring your table so that `SELECT * FROM table WHERE itemID = ? AND itemType = ?` will give you all the rows you want, with all the columns you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a trick with `INNER JOIN`, put all possible records of dropdown in a table as I called it `tblDropDownItems` with an extra column refer to ItemType, when you join this table with filtered table `TblItem`, you just have the related records to the retrieved item type:

```
SELECT tblDropDownItems.TaskID, tblDropDownItems.TaskName
FROM
    (SELECT 0 AS TaskID, 'Installation' AS TaskName, 'B' AS ItemType
     UNION
     SELECT 1 AS TaskID, 'Setup' AS TaskName, 'B' AS ItemType
     UNION
     SELECT 2 AS TaskID, 'Feedback' AS TaskName, 'B' AS ItemType
     UNION
     SELECT 3 AS TaskID, 'Customer' AS TaskName, 'B' AS ItemType
     UNION
     SELECT 4 AS TaskID, 'Production' AS TaskName, 'P' AS ItemType
     UNION
     SELECT 5 AS TaskID, 'Debug' AS TaskName, 'P' AS ItemType
     UNION
     SELECT 6 AS TaskID, 'Review' AS TaskName, 'P' AS ItemType
     UNION
     SELECT 7 AS TaskID, 'Network' AS TaskName, 'P' AS ItemType
     UNION
     . . . your select clause for 'S' ItemType
     UNION
     . . . your select clause for 'O' ItemType) tblDropDownItems
INNER JOIN
     (SELECT ItemType
      FROM TblItem
      WHERE ItemID = [ItemID]) tblItemType
ON tblDropDownItems.ItemType = tblItemType.ItemType
```

Comment: It would be better just to redesign the table to include that information.

Comment: @MatBailie if he authorized to redesigning tables in DB It would better to have a table like tblDropDownItems in DB.

Answer (score 1):

A case statement in SQL is used for a very different case: it makes a case switch on row-by-row basis, so not on the query level.

I think it would be much easier to create a new table containing the items you wish to store in your drop down, then use the itemId to select the correct rows from this table and populate the drop down. Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `dropdown` (
TaskID int(11) NOT NULL,
TaskName varchar(32) NOT NULL,
ItemID int(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(TaskID));
```

In this case you don't have to use a CASE statement and directly select all necessary rows from the table. And you probably could even do this in one query using a join.